# SQL Server execute different queries for a list of inputs

Tags: sql-server

I want to execute different queries for a list of different inputs.
For example:

`Lets say different inputs are, name = 'abc1','abc2','abc3'`

Queries to execute are:

```
1)some large sql query taking input as 'abc1'
2)another large sql query taking input as 'abc1'
```

Same is to be repeated for all the inputs, i.e, abc2, abc3...
'

Comment: why cant you try `select * from table1 where name in ('abc1','abc2','abc3')` ?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, do you need to return the results for all 5 queries in a single data table? Do you need the results to be returned once per each element in the input list, or one result for the entire list?

Answer (score 0):

u can put all queries in union ex.

```
select * from table1 where name='abc1' union
select * from table2 where name='abc2' union
select * from table3 where name='abc3' union
select * from table4 where name='abc4' union
select * from table5 where name='abc5'
```

Comment: Use UNION ALL in case you don't want duplicate rows to be removed.

Comment: its obvious that one query result can not come in another query result in this scenario ..so union all gets same result as union